# Devtools/library download error

Tags: r, rstudio, devtools

I am trying to install Devtools into Rstudio. I was using Rgui, but decided to use Rstudio becuase it seems to be easier. I able to get DevTools on Rgui, but not RStudio.

Basicly. the library on Rstudio does not have DEVtools installed and I am having problems. Any ideas?

I tried the install.packages("devtools") states it is install in y computer, but does not show in the library. I tried GitHub. did not wok either.

```
install.packages("devtools")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Steven/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying                                                                     

    URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/devtools_1.10.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 391482 bytes (382 KB)
downloaded 382 KB
package ‘devtools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot remove prior installation of package ‘devtools’
```

The downloaded binary packages are in

```
C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpkxtbPl\downloaded_packages
```

However, I do Library(devtools) states Error in library(devtools) : there is no package called ‘devtool